# Plot sklearn LinearRegression output with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

After importing the file when I separate the x_values and y_values using numpy as:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
from  matplotlib import pyplot 
import numpy as np

#read data
dataframe = pd.read_csv('challenge_dataset.txt')
dataframe.columns=['Brain','Body']
x_values=np.array(dataframe['Brain'],dtype=np.float64).reshape(1,-1)
y_values=np.array(dataframe['Body'],dtype=np.float64).reshape(1,-1)

#train model on data
body_reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
body_reg.fit(x_values, y_values)
prediction=body_reg.predict(x_values)

print(prediction)
#visualize results
pyplot.scatter(x_values, y_values)
pyplot.plot(x_values,prediction)
pyplot.show()
```

I get the plot as following image, which doesn't show up the line of best fit and also when I print the value of 'prediction' it shows up values same as 'y_values'.

[image]
Contrary when I use the following code. I get the regression line.

```
#read data
dataframe = pd.read_csv('challenge_dataset.txt')
dataframe.columns=['Brain','Body']
x_values=dataframe[['Brain']]
y_values=dataframe[['Body']]
```

[image]

Why is it so ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would be the reason to do `.reshape(1,-1)`?

Comment: `x_values=np.array(dataframe['Brain'],dtype=np.float64).reshape(1,-1)` Because I was taking the value of column `Brain` in 1 dimension. I know it's weird I could have taken it in 2 dimension but I was just experimenting.

Comment: What I mean is what happens if you leave `.reshape(1,-1)` out?

Comment: It throws this error. **ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(X,y)`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit) expects its arguments

> `X` : numpy array or sparse matrix of shape `[n_samples,n_features]`
>   `y` : numpy array of shape `[n_samples, n_targets]`

Here you have 1 "feature" and 1 "target", hence the expected shape of the input would be `(n_samples,1)`

While this is the case for

```
x_values=dataframe[['Brain']]
y_values=dataframe[['Body']]
```

the shape for `np.array(dataframe['Brain'],dtype=np.float64).reshape(1,-1)` is `(n_samples,)`.

Another option to optain the desired shape from the dataframe columns would be to broadcast them to a 2D array with a new axis

```
x_values=dataframe['Brain'].values[:,np.newaxis]
y_values=dataframe['Body'].values[:,np.newaxis]
```

Note that in order to show a nice line, you would probably want to sort the x values.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
from  matplotlib import pyplot 
import numpy as np

#read data
x = np.random.rand(25,2)
x[:,1] = 2*x[:,0]+np.random.rand(25)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(x,columns=['Brain','Body'])


x_values=dataframe['Brain'].values[:,np.newaxis]
y_values=dataframe['Body'].values[:,np.newaxis]

body_reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
body_reg.fit(x_values, y_values)
prediction=body_reg.predict(np.sort(x_values, axis=0))

pyplot.scatter(x_values, y_values)
pyplot.plot(np.sort(x_values, axis=0),prediction)
pyplot.show()
```

[image]